# How to detect if the SQLite DB already created

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

To avoid creating double SQLite DB, How to detect if there is one already ?

1) Below code is creating SQLite DB in App.xaml.cs

2) Is this code in App.xaml.cs  creating a SQLite DB or creating just Table or BOTH?

3) in MainPage, How Do I check One more time if SQLite DB is created.

Problem:
no erro message and MainPage is not showing.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

```
 -- In below checking rootFrame in  App.xaml.cs

if (rootFrame == null)
{


 //-- Detect before creating 

 bool result = await GetIfFileExistsAsync(DBPath);


 if (result == true)               
 {
      MessageDialog mError = new MessageDialog("DB Created", "DB creation status");
     await mError.ShowAsync();
     return;

 }
 else
  {
    MessageDialog mError = new MessageDialog("DB NOT Created", "NO DB created");
   await mError.ShowAsync();

   CreateDBNow();

   }

//---- rootFrame

}




 private async Task GetIfFileExistsAsync(string strDBPath)
 {
    try
     {

     var dbFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(strDBPath);

      if (dbFile != null)
      {
       return true;
      }
     else
      {
        return false;
      }


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
      return false;

    }
 }

 private async void CreateDBNow()
 {

    DBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "customers.sqlite");


   using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
   {
    // Create the tables if they don't exist
    db.CreateTable();

   }

  MessageDialog mError = new MessageDialog("DB now created", "DB created");
  await mError.ShowAsync();


  }


--- in MainPage 


I need to check one more time if SQLite DB is created.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice developers store database in local folder, so below given handy method will help you. WinRT doesn't have feature to check whether file exist or not. So this is applicable to check not only for database file but all `StorageFile`.

```csharp
public async Task<bool> IsDatabaseExistsAsync(string DatabaseNameWithExtension)
{
    try
    {
        var dbFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(DatabaseNameWithExtension);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet gives the result that DB file is existed or not. Here I have a doubt, In snippet code in the question `String DBPath` will search for  database file in given path & If file exists it will create a DB connection otherwise Create file with given name in the path. AFAIK the Dbfile is not creating two files.
Am I right...?

Comment: I would recommend to check for database in `App.xaml.cs`'s `OnLaunched(...)` method. If `IsDatabaseExistsAsync(..)` return false then & then create database otherwise navigate to app's first page to be opened.

Comment: Yeap. I am doing same thing as OnLaunched() in App.xaml.cs
Then as I said here two files are not created. Just checking the file is exist or not with the given path.
Why asking means I am using as same as Snippet code in question.
Waiting for ur valuable reply

Comment: Is the above detect method Ok to create SQLite DB?

Comment: Do I just use a name like customer.sqlite without a Path or with a path like this Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "customers.sqlite") to create DB. How do I re-check again in MainPage after created the DB in App.xaml.cs ? Does your code need Filename with path or without path when using in MainPage?

Comment: Sorry , I mean checking the DB exits in other page not Main Page